# using continue in LLDB stops the process and throws a SIGSEGV

Tags: android, android-ndk, lldb

I'm trying to debug a native C++ App that is crashing using `lldb`

*I also have a `sleep(5)` at the start of `android_main` so that I can attach to my app in that time, if that matters*

After attaching the app is paused/stopped. So, I use `continue`

But the process is immediately stopped after using `continue` and throws a `SIGSEGV`

```
(lldb) continue
Process 4158 resuming
Process 4158 stopped
* thread #19, name = 'com.example.app', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00007cefe26282c8
->  0x7cefe26282c8: movq   (%rcx), %rdx
    0x7cefe26282cb: movq   %rdx, 0x18a0(%rax)
    0x7cefe26282d2: movl   0x8(%rcx), %ecx
    0x7cefe26282d5: movl   %ecx, 0x18a8(%rax)
```

After another `continue`, the app just exits/crashes

```
(lldb) continue
Process 4158 exited with status = 11 (0x0000000b)
```

**How do I fix this and just continue execution as normal?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app crashed because the register `rcx` was supposed to hold the address of some object, but in fact held a value that was not in readable memory.  That's what `SIGSEGV` means - a request was made to access memory that couldn't be fulfilled.  You can't "continue execution as normal" since the program didn't get some data it needs, so it doesn't have a way to move forward.  If you knew the value that SHOULD have been in `rcx`, you could set `rcx` to the right value, and then continue.  But what you really have to do is figure out why that value was bad, fix the code, rebuild and rerun.